# How to implement Android Multi-item listview like iOS UITableView

Tags: android, ios, listview, multiple-columns

Now I am implementing chat screen in an Android App.
the use of the adapter pattern of ListView seems to be the best one cell.
You know you need a cell of a different type of user messages, photos, videos, dates, announcements, etc in chat screen.

Conventional methods that I know of is two things.

1. In getView() method, create each time a new type of cell.
2. First of all, put all the item and ,in getView() method, adjust the UI layout by VISIBLE/GONE options.

The second method is better i thought, but this method is still a waste of memory and complexity to implement.

For UITableView of iOS generate multiple queue by the number of type of cell. It is efficiently in Multi-Item ListView.
there any easy way to implement as iOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) instead of `ListView`.

Create `xml` file for each item view. Create `ViewHolder` for each file `xml`.

Inside `Adapter` of `RecyclerView` override `getItemViewType()` return view type correspond with it's position. Override `onCreateViewHodler`which return `ViewHolder` correspond with view type. Finally, override `onBindViewHolder` bind your data to your layout.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using this library [JSQMessagesViewController](https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController) its very flexible and scalable.

Comment: Is there any Android version of JSQMessagesViewController?